# Teichmüller space on non-orientable closed surfaces

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, teichmuller-theory

It is known that any closed orientable surface of genus $g \geq 2$ admits a hyperbolic metric, and the Teichmüller space of such metrics has dimension $6g - 6$. I was wondering if there is a corresponding statement for non-orientable closed surfaces of negative Euler characteristic. By the Gauss-Bonnet theorem and Ricci flow theory, for example, I can see that such surfaces admit many hyperbolic metrics, but I am not sure about the structure of the space of such metrics.

Also, on the Teichmüller space for a genus $g \geq 2$ closed orientable surface, there is a concept of distance (see, for example, Definition 6.4.1 of Buser's book "Geometry and spectra of compact Riemann surfaces"). Is there a similar concept in the non-orientable case? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Send me an email, I am preparing a nice paper about it, hassan.jolany@gmail.com

Answer (score 3):

There is a nice paper by Pablo Ares Gastesi, where lots of standard results are generalized to that setting (there is an arxiv.org preprint, as well).

```
Gastesi, P.A., 1997. Some results on Teichmueller spaces of Klein surfaces. Glasgow Mathematical Journal, 39(01), pp.65-76.
```

Answer (score 3):

A very nice paper about the Teichm\"uller space of non-orientable surfaces, Fenchel-Nielsen coordinates and other generalizations of Thurston's theory to non-orientable surfaces is this one by Papadopoulos and Penner:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.0383.pdf